# getting the last occurence of a certain item in a sql request

Tags: sql, psql

I am trying to write sql requests to my database in order to get the last occurence of a certain item, here's what I mean illustrated by an example:

```
pigc=# SELECT date FROM msr_history WHERE pos = 'DV' AND msr_id = 177;
            date            
----------------------------
 2018-06-20 08:04:09.724103
 2018-06-20 08:09:49.484921
(2 rows)
```

The first line of my example is my sql request and I am trying to get only the last date,  in this example it would be this one: `2018-06-20 08:09:49.484921`
Note that the number of dates can differ so I can't just manualy select the second date each time. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Anything wrong with `max(date)` ?

Comment: I did not expect this to be so simple... haha Thank you very much, I was unaware of the existence of max(). If you want me to accept your answer I will gladly do so if you make an answer out of this :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `select max(column)` to retrieve the highest value for that specific data type for all rows included in the `where` clause.

In this instance, no aggregation is required since no non-aggregated columns are being retrieved.

See [https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html) for a complete list of aggregate functions and specifically https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-max-function

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to achieve it to use the LIMIT clause in your query. This will prevent using aggregate function in your query and will run fastest -

```
SELECT date
  FROM msr_history
 WHERE pos = 'DV'
   AND msr_id = 177
 ORDER BY date DESC
 LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: It's actually more likely to be the other way round, with a sutable index performance will be comparable, otherwise limit 1 with order by will perform worse due to the sort.